# Arm Polygons attached to Clothes Polygons?

Tags: animation, rigging, weight-painting, vertex-weights

Hi Blender Community,

so i tried to set a rig for this Character and everything seems to be fine except for one thing:

When i move the Hand Bone around the Polygons of the Pants follow (the whole Mesh is one Object the Clothes are not seperate)

[image]

Since the Character wasn't build by me, i can not change the Mesh and as seen in the picture (right side)  the original Pose isn't T. Also the Forearm and upper Arm are attached to the polygons aswell. -.-

[image]

The first thing that came to my mind was, well maybe it's because of the weight painting but i checked and its doesn't look like that's the problem because there is no weight of the other Bones on the Pants.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Maybe there is trouble with the vertex Groups ? Could it be that ? I personally don't really now how to define which vertices are part of each group because i'm still learning Blender. Does someone know a Solution for my case ?

Best regards

Debbie

Answer (score 1):

This **is** due to weight painting, just not the bone your using.  when your moving a bone and it's moving part of the mesh you don't want it to, and the weight painting seems to be normal, check all the bones that are parented to the bone your moving.  in this case, check the fingers.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: You are right ! I was just in the wrong Panel, thats why it didn't show me ALL of the Finger Weights thanks :)

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Comment: hey, if my answer fixed the problem, could you mark it as accepted? :)